# Bernoulli generator

Tags: operator-theory

I'm new at these things. How will I use the generator

$B_n(z)=\frac{D}{e^D-1}z^n$ where $D= \frac{d}{dz}$ is differentiation with respect to $z$ and the fraction is expanded as a formal power series.

How will I let the operator $D$ act on $z^n$? D is defined as d/dz. I have the idea of expanding $exp$ as a power series and applying $z^n$ to both the numerator and denominator.

Sorry for asking a stupid question. I am not a math major and my math background is only on complex analysis, ODEs, linear algebra, and calculus.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It would help if you provide the context of your question. What do you mean by *"generator"*? In which space if the operator $D$ defined?

Comment: I'm sorry! I am not really a math major but I am trying to study operators. I may have used the term "generator" in the wrong way, my bad.

There was no explicit definition for the space of D from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials. D is the differential operator d/dz. As for now, I am just trying to get on how to use the formula given above. It would be really thankful if you could tell me what topics I could study regarding this area as well. I really have no background in math except for complex analysis, calculus, linear algebra, and ODE's and some PDEs

Comment: Understood... However, I doubt that you'll have pertinent answers if you do not provide more context.

Comment: Indeed $D=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}$ acts upon $z^n$ via $Dz^n = nz^{n-1}$ (as well as $D1 = 0$). So, if $\frac{D}{e^D-1}=\sum_{k\geq0}a_kD^k$ as a formal power series, then $$\frac{D}{e^D-1}z^n=\sum_{k\geq0}a_kD^kz^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n!a_k}{(n-k)!}z^{n-k}. $$

Comment: Thank you for your response, Dr. Lee.

Answer (score 3):

Expand $\frac{D}{e^D-1}$ as a formal series around the origin as

$$\frac{D}{e^D-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_n D^n.$$

Then apply this formal operator to $z^n$. You get a polynomial as only a finite number of derivatives are not vanishing.

Comment: Thank you for lending your time gentlemen! Last question. In this case, I have a good idea about what the coefficient $a_n$ is. However, it is my first time to deal with expansions involving an operator (i.e, d/dz) without a test function besides it. How would I determine $a_n$ in this case? 

What books would you recommend for me to cover? For reference, I am trying to get into the area of hyperdifferential operators (with very minimal knowledge) and I am just trying to reproduce results from papers with zero background knowledge about the basics haha

Comment: Ahh never mind! I have just to match the coefficients in the right hand side i guess. my bad hehe. Thanks for your time!